# Suspended event handling with C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, semaphore, autoresetevent

I have 2 classes:

```
public class A
{
    private const int MAXCOUNTER = 100500;
    private Thread m_thrd;
    public event Action<string> ItemStarted;
    public event Action<string> ItemFinished;

    private void OnItemStarted(string name)
    {
        if (ItemStarted != null) ItemStarted(name);
    }

    private void OnItemFinished(string name)
    {
        if (ItemFinished != null) ItemFinished(name);
    }

    public A()
    {
        m_thrd = new Thread(this.Run);
        m_thrd.Start();
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAXCOUNTER; i++)
        {
            OnItemStarted(i.ToString());
            // some long term operations
            OnItemFinished(i.ToString());
        }
    }
}

public class B
{
    private Thread m_thrd;
    private Queue<string> m_data;
    public B()
    {
        m_thrd = new Thread(this.ProcessData);
        m_thrd.Start();
    }

    public void ItemStartedHandler(string str)
    {
        m_data.Enqueue(str);
    }

    public void ItemFinishedHandler(string str)
    {
        if (m_data.Dequeue() != str)
            throw new Exception("dequeued element is not the same as finish one!");
    }

    private void ProcessData()
    {
        lock (m_data)
        {
            while (m_data.Count != 0)
            {
                var item = m_data.Peek();
                //make some long term operations on the item
            }
        }
    }
}
```

also we have somewhere else in code

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
a.ItemStarted += b.ItemStartedHandler;
a.ItemFinished += b.ItemFinishedHandler;
```

- So, if `ItemFinished` is raised while `ProcessData()` is still working, what will happen?
- Should I use something like `AutoResetEvent` to make class `A` wait on class `B` finishes `ProcessData`?
- Is it necessary to use `lock` in `ProcessData`?
- Is it ok to invoke thread of class `B` with `m_thrd = new Thread(this.ProcessData);`? The thing is confusing me here - won't `ProcessData` finish before any `ItemStarted` event is raised (won't it lead to situation when thread in `B` already is finished when `ItemStarted` is generated first time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit of a threading mess.

Your first issue is a race condition if `ItemFinished` is raised before `ProcessData()` is finished.

Don't worry about using `AutoResetEvent`. The simple thing is to lock every access to `m_data`. So that leads to the next quertion - yes, the lock is necessary and it's necessary everywhere.

But your final point is the most important. You need to change each of the constructors to a `.Start()` method to allow time to wire up before you begin.

But, even then you have a massive race condition.

Here's what you should do to make this work. NuGet "Rx-Main" to add Microsoft's Reactive Framework to your code. Then do this:

```
var scheduler1 = new EventLoopScheduler();
var scheduler2 = new EventLoopScheduler();

Observable
    .Range(0, 100500)
    .ObserveOn(scheduler1)
    .Do(x => { /* some long term operations */ })
    .ObserveOn(scheduler2)
    .Subscribe(x =>
    {
        //make some long term operations on the item
    });
```

Job done.

Comment: thanks for the respond. but I have to use threads explicitly here.

Comment: This does explicitly use threads. The event loop schedulers each schedule using a single thread.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct few threading issues in your code:

1. You are wiring up events after starting threads. You should do this before starting threads. So, for both the classes, put whatever is in constructor in a Public instance function. Now create instances of your classes, wire up events and then call instance method of class B first and then class A to start threads.
2. You are accessing Queue in class B from two different threads. Queue is not thread safe, so instead, you should be using ConcurrentQueue (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx) and corresponding Try... Functions. You would not require any kind of explicit locking with ConcurrentQueue.
3. Your intent for using class B ProcessData function is not very clear. Do you want to call ProcessData once for every item in the Queue or you want to keep on calling ProcessData until item is not Dequeued? If, former is the case then instead of using Queue you should be using BlockingCollection With GetConsumingEnumerable. See this for detail: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186(v=vs.110).aspx. I can post a sample if this is what you want. If you use BlockingCollection then there will be no case where ProcessData finish earlier then class A thread.

Comment: I have to be mo specific here: I have one class to pick info about dir and files in it (recursively go through whole tree) and 2 classes to store data in file and show in UI. General idea is to put folder names in a stack (it's processed in the same thread of cl. A) and file info in queue (cl. B). When all files from the dir are in queue A hangs until B process them in separate thread. I'm using CountdownEvent (because there are 2 additional threads - so to say instances of B) andThread.Join() for purpose of synchronization due to initial requirements - not to use TPL, concurrent coll's etc.